# Simple way to encrypt data in winrt

Tags: encryption, windows-runtime, data-protection

I am trying to encrypt a string with Windows RT. Before it was possible to use the `ProtectData` in the `system.security` namespace but that does not exist in WinRT. I tried to use the following code but it does not work.

```cs
public static async Task<string> EncryptSting(string data)
{
    DataProtectionProvider provider = new DataProtectionProvider();

    IBuffer unprotectedData = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(data, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    //crashes here
    IBuffer protectedData = await provider.ProtectAsync(unprotectedData);

    return CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, protectedData);
}

public static async Task<string> DecryptString(string data)
{
    DataProtectionProvider provider = new DataProtectionProvider();

    IBuffer inputData = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(data, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    //crashes here
    IBuffer unprotectedData = await provider.UnprotectAsync(inputData);

    return CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, unprotectedData);
}
```

**Edit:** The execption is

> The supplied handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090026)

and it occurs on the 3rd line when encrypting and decrypting

Comment: Exactly how it "does not work"? Does not compile, does not produce expected results, throws exceptions? You question is to broad as is, please provide additional details.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/br241561.aspx), the constructor you're using can only be used for decryption, not for encryption:

> Constructor used for decryption operations. Use this constructor before calling the `UnprotectAsync` or `UnprotectStreamAsync` methods.

For encryption, you must use the other constructor, which specifies if the data should be encrypted for the local machine, current user, specific user, etc.

I don't know why it doesn't work for decryption in your case, but if encryption doesn't work, I'm not sure what you're trying to decrypt...

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the following:

```
public static async Task<string> EncryptSting(string data)
{
    DataProtectionProvider provider = new DataProtectionProvider("LOCAL=user");
    ...
    ...
}
```

Cheers!